# Regex backreferences in Java

Tags: java, regex

I had to match a number followed by itself 14 times. Then I've came to the following regular expression in the [regexstor.net/tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5Cd%29%5C1%7B14%7D&i=000000000000000%0D%0A111111111111111%0D%0A222222222222222%0D%0A333333333333333%0D%0A444444444444444%0D%0A999999999999999%0D%0A888888888888888%0D%0A1231654987%2A9897%0D%0A123165498463132%0D%0A215449879%2A41325%0D%0A2231354987843511):

```
(\d)\1{14}
```

**Edit**

When I paste it in my code, including the backslashes properly:

```
"(\\d)\\1{14}"
```

I've replaced the back-reference `"\1"` by the `"$1"` which is used to replace matches in Java.

Then I've realized that it doesn't work. When you need to back-reference a match in the REGEX, in Java, you have to use `"\N"`, but when you want to replace it, the operator is `"$N"`.

My question is: why?

Comment: That is not just Java, in most of the regex flavors `\N` is back-reference in regex pattern. `$` has special meaning in regex

Comment: Yes, "$" means the end of expression, but why they don't use `\N` to replace too?

Comment: Some of them like `python`, `sed` or `perl` do allow `\N` in replacement but Java designers decided `$` notation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$1` is not a back reference in Java's regexes, nor in any other flavor I can think of. You only use `$1` when you are *replacing* something:

```
String input="A12.3 bla bla my input";
input = StringUtils.replacePattern(
            input, "^([A-Z]\\d{2}\\.\\d).*$", "$1");
//                                            ^^^^
```

There is some misinformation about what a back reference is, including the very place I got that snippet from: [simple java regex with backreference does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30535364).

---

Java modeled its regex syntax after other existing flavors where the `$` was already a meta character. It anchors to the end of the string (or line in multi-line mode).

Similarly, Java uses `\1` for back references. Because regexes are strings, it must be escaped: `\\1`.

From a lexical/syntactic standpoint it is true that `$1` could be used unambiguously (as a bonus it would prevent the need for the "evil escaped escape" when using back references).

To match a `1` that comes after the end of a line the regex would need to be `$\n1`:

```
this line
1
```

It just makes more sense to use a familiar syntax instead of changing the rules, most of which came from Perl.

The first version of Perl came out in [1987](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlhist.html), which is much earlier than Java, which was released in beta in [1995](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history).

I dug up the [man pages for Perl 1](http://www-cgi.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/Web/People/rgs/pl-regex.html), which say:

> The bracketing construct `(\ ...\ )` may also be used, in which case `\<digit>` matches the `digit`'th substring. (Outside of the pattern, always use `$` instead of `\` in front of the digit. The scope of `$<digit>` (and `` $\` ``, `$&` and `$'`) extends to the end of the enclosing BLOCK or eval string, or to the next pattern match with subexpressions. The `\<digit>` notation sometimes works outside the current pattern, but should not be relied upon.) You may have as many parentheses as you wish. If you have more than 9 substrings, the variables `$10`, `$11`, ... refer to the corresponding substring. Within the pattern, `\10`, `\11`, etc. refer back to substrings if there have been at least that many left parens before the backreference. Otherwise (for backward compatibilty) `\10` is the same as `\010`, a backspace, and `\11` the same as `\011`, a tab. And so on. (`\1` through `\9` are always backreferences.)

Comment: "Java modeled its regex syntax after other existing flavors where the $ was already a meta character. It anchors to the end of the string (or line in multi-line mode)" makes sense. Do you have any source?

Comment: @Jaumzera I do now ;)

Comment: I don't know what's "evil escaped escape", could you provide a link to it?

Comment: @Raining In other regex flavors, you can just have a single escape character: `\1`. In Java, you must escape that escape: `\\1`. This is clearly evil.

Comment: @Laurel you saved my life. I didn't know in Java the numeric reference had to be scaped with double bar \\...I agree, this is clearly evil haha.

Answer (score 3):

I think the main Problem is not the backreference - which works perfectly fine with `\1` in java.

Your Problem is more likely the "overall" escaping of a regex pattern in Java.

If you want to have the pattern

```
(\d)\1{14}
```

passed to the regex engine, you first need to escape it cause it's a java-string when you write it:

```
(\\d)\\1{14}
```

Voila, works like a charm: goo.gl/BNCx7B (add http://, SO does not allow Url-Shorteners, but tutorialspoint.com has no other option as it seems)

Offline-Example:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String test = "555555555555555"; // 5 followed by 5 for 14 times.

        String pattern = "(\\d)\\1{14}";

        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = r.matcher(test);
        if (m.find( )) {
           System.out.println("Matched!");   
        }else{
           System.out.println("not matched :-(");    
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for attention, @dognose. I do know about String/Regex escaping in Java. I've realized that I should put it in the question. I'm editing it right now.

Comment: @Jaumzera Just see the example i provided - if the escaped pattern does not work - then your error is somewhere else, but not within the "pattern". (Are you sure that you have 15 times the same number? (cause you said 1 + 14 followers) - and not only 14 in total?)

Comment: Well, I've get your point. But my doubt was about the replacement operator itself not about the regex. Thank for your time. +one.

Comment: Doesn't work for me if I use `([0-9]{2}-)\\1{2}[0-9]{2}` or `([0-9]{2})-\\1-\\1-\\1`