# Can we replace a specific part of a string literal using any predefined function and regex

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, replaceall

I want to replace "&" with a random word "$d" in a given sentence.
Can we replace only those words which start with & and are followed by a single character and a space?

Example:-

**Input:-**

**Two literals are &a and &b and also check &abc and &bac here.**

**Output:-**

**Two literals are $da and $db and also check &abc and &bac here.**

In the above example in input, the only words that should be replaced are &a and &b(not the complete word should be replaced, only just the '&' in both the words) because these two random words start with & and are followed by a single character and a space.

In the case of the replaceAll() function, it replaces the entire word when I used regex:-

```
String str="Two literals are &a and &b and also check &abc and &bac here.";

str = str.replaceAll("\\&[a-zA-Z]{1}\\s", "\\$d");

System.out.println(str);

//output for this:-Two literals are $d and $d and also check &abc and &bac here.

//expected output:-Two literals are $da and $db and also check &abc and &bac here.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code for this would be

```
str.replaceAll("&([a-zA-Z]\\s)", "\\$d$1")
```

This is an example of backreferencing captured groups in regex, and [a here is a nice reference for it](https://dzone.com/articles/backreferences-java-regular). Additionally, [here's a relevant StackOverflow question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37734164/regex-backreferences-in-java).

Essentially, the match inside the parentheses (`[a-zA-Z]\\s`) matches a single letter and a space. The value of this match can be referenced with `$1` since it is of capturing group 1.

So we replace `&(a )` with `$d(a )` (brackets here to demonstrate what is captured). Credit to u/rzwitserloot for reminding me that OP wants $ not &.

Comment: This does not work. Example input that would fail: `"This is $a"`. In general not salvagable, I think - the right answer is lookahead. I'm penning an answer now.

Comment: Ahh good point. But the OP mentioned that the match should have a space ahead of it, so I assumed it must necessarily be a "word" type of token, so I took it literally. Regardless, +1 for noting that.

Comment: Also OP wants `$d` not `&d`, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You presumably want a concept called look-ahead: You can match on things being there without 'consuming' it. You can even match on things NOT being there. That's what you want here: Match `&[a-z]`, but only if looking ahead past that, we do NOT see another letter:

```
for (String test : List.of("Two literals are &a and &bcd", "A literal is &a", "How about &a?")) {
  System.out.println(str.replaceAll("&(?=[a-zA-Z](?![a-zA-Z]))", "\\$d"));
}
```

Perhaps instead you want the single letter thing to just be on any word break (i.e. `&z00` should NOT turn into `$dz00`, even though there is no letter after the `z`. Then I suggest:

`"&(?=[a-zA-Z]\\b)"`

That's a lot simpler to read!

A few notes:

- `(?=x)` is 'positive lookahead'. It doesn't itself match anything but makes the match fail if `x` is not immediately following the match.
- `(?!x)` is 'negative lookahead'. It doesn't itself match anything but makes the match fail if `x` *is* immediately following the match.
- `$` has special meaning in the replacement part so we need to escape it.
- `\\b` is regexpese for 'word break': Doesn't match any characters, but fails if we aren't on a 'word break'. Spaces, dots, end-of-input, end-of-line, a dash, an ampersand - many things are word breaks.
- We don't want to match those letters because if we do, they would be replaced.